# Android - How to compare data of a key with other keys data in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is just a demo data. I am using `JAVA.` So, I know how to fetch data from firebase but, what I want to know is how can I compare all the data of `KEY` i.e. `user 1` with `user 2` and `user 3` and show it in percentage.

For example - If I compare `user 1 data` with `user 2` data then it should show 50% similar or dissimilar. Similarly, for `user1` and `user3`, it should show 0% similarity.

So, how can I compare and show the similar or dissimilar in percentage? Any Idea?

Comment: Will you have more than three users in your `test` node?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I will have more than 3 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
    private static float checkSimilarity(String u1, String u2) {
        String s[] = u1.split(",");
        int count = 0;
        
        for(String v : s) {
            if(u2.contains(v.trim())) count++;
        }

        return ((float)count/s.length)*100; 
    }
```

Comment: The code is working but, It is comparing user1 data user3 data skipping the user2 data. Any Suggestions what should I do?

Comment: The first parameter will be that user, with who respect you want to compare and the second user will be the user you want to compare.

Comment: You need to call this function multiple times if you change any of the user. There is a way in which you can fix your user with who you can respect to compare and iterate over all other remaining user using and loop and call the function inside this. Hope this help you 

Comment: @HarshAshra Does this satisfy your query or there is something more that I can help you with?

Comment: Sorry for being Inactive. I have one more query If I store data that I am fetching from firebase in an ArrayList So, Is there any way to compare them?

Comment: You can try 2 ways.... 1st iterate over both ArrayList or you can just iterate over the one and use something like this `user1.get(v)` ...here v will be an object of `String`.. if thes statement returns you something then it is present in array or if it is null then not present. I will recommend if you put a new question so that I can answer you in more efficient and effective way with an sample code. Hope this will help 

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

1. You know how to retrieve data from firebase.
2. The data is stored as an object of the type User model.

Rough Pseudocode:
user1 and user2 are objects of type User.

```
float userSimilarity(user1,user2)
{
   String[] likes1=user1.likes.split(",");
   String[] likes2=user2.likes.split(",");
   int count=0;
   if(likes1.length()>=likes2.length())
   {
       for(int i=0;i<likes1.length();i++)
           for(int j=0;j<likes2.length();2++)
               if(likes1[i].trim()==likes2[j].trim()) count++;
       return (count/likes1.length());
   }
   else
   {
       for(int i=0;i<likes2.length();i++)
           for(int j=0;j<likes1.length();2++)
               if(likes2[i].trim()==likes1[j].trim()) count++;
       return (count/likes2.length());
   } 
}
```

Comment: So, I have to call this method inside **OnDataChange** ?

Comment: Depends. U do that after u retrieve the data and store it in 2 objects and when you want to display the similarity on the screen.

Comment: Apart from this, Is their any other way?

Comment: I doubt it. You must compare it always.